# Is there any good Terran (SC2) replay pack of one player?

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to see how his build (whatever it is) work with different opponents.
(And of course steal and perfect it :) )

Answer (score 2):

Here are a list of Brad_OK Vods which you will find more useful:

- [TvP](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/3752216/)
- TvT [Part 1](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/3761605/), [Part 2](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/3761743/)
- TvZ [Part 1](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/3757291/), [Part 2](http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/3757580/)

But you asked for a replay pack, not Vods.

There aren't a ton of replay packs that are SC2 compatible, most are only compatible with the beta.  The issue is that SC2 hasn't been out long enough for good replay packs to be coming out.